# Giving user defined functions non-quoted arguments in purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm learning quasiquotation and quotation with [rlang](/questions/tagged/rlang). My function looks at if any `forbidden_values` occur in any of the mentioned [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) variables `selectlist`, and marks a row with any positive result as `1`, else `0`.

- How can I make rlang interpret non-quoted input to the argument selectlist in the function environment instead of the global environment?
- As I'm supplying a list of values, why do I have to use `!!` instead of `!!!`?
- Why can I supply the anonymous [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) formula any function with the `dot-dot-dot` operator?

*This function works only with variable names to selectlist in quotes " " .*

```
selectlist <- function(df, selectlist, forbidden_values){
  enquos(selectlist)
  enquos(forbidden_values)


  df %>% mutate(is_injured = purrr::pmap_int(select(.,!!selectlist), ~any(c(...) %in% !!forbidden_values)))

}
```

## Works

```
selectlist(expected, selectlist=c("PrimaryInjury","SecondaryInjury"),forbidden_values=c("Rust","Insect","Snow break"))
```

```
  plantid year PrimaryInjury SecondaryInjury OtherInjury is_injured
1        1    1          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
2        1    2        Insect            <NA>        <NA>          1
3        1    3          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
4        2    1          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
5        2    2          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
6        2    3          Rust            <NA>        <NA>          1
7        3    1          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
8        3    2          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
9        3    3          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
10       4    1          Rust            <NA>        <NA>          1
11       4    2          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
12       4    3        Insect            <NA>        <NA>          1
13       5    1    Snow break            <NA>        <NA>          1
14       5    2          Rust            <NA>        <NA>          1
15       5    3          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
```

## Doesn't work

```
selectlist(expected, selectlist=c(PrimaryInjury,SecondaryInjury),forbidden_values=c("Rust","Insect","Snow break"))
```

> Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named =
>   named,  :    object 'PrimaryInjury' not found

Thank you for helping...

*Example dataframe: expected*

```
plantid <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), times=c(3,3,3,3,3))
year <- rep(1:3, length.out=length(plantid))
set.seed(42)
PrimaryInjury <- sample(c(NA,NA,NA,"Rust","Insect","Snow break"), 15, replace=TRUE)
SecondaryInjury <- rep(NA, length.out=length(plantid))
OtherInjury <- rep(NA, length.out=length(plantid))

expected <- data.frame(plantid,year,PrimaryInjury,SecondaryInjury, OtherInjury)

#All in selectlist must be characters.
expected$PrimaryInjury <- as.character(expected$PrimaryInjury)
expected$SecondaryInjury <- as.character(expected$SecondaryInjury)
expected$OtherInjury <- as.character(expected$OtherInjury)
```

---

*dput of `expected`*

```
structure(list(plantid = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 5), year = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), PrimaryInjury = c(NA, "Insect", NA, NA, NA, 
"Rust", NA, NA, NA, "Rust", NA, "Insect", "Snow break", "Rust", 
NA), SecondaryInjury = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), OtherInjury = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @RonakShah dput of expected output included.

Comment: @RonakShah I realised I should've named that something different! My bad, I've included a dput and the code to create the example data.frame "expected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok to pass unquoted variables separately, we can use three dots

```
selectlist <- function(df, forbidden_values, ...){

    df %>% mutate(is_injured = purrr::pmap_int(select(.,...), 
                               ~any(c(...) %in% forbidden_values)))
}

selectlist(expected, forbidden_values= c("Rust","Insect","Snow break"), 
                      PrimaryInjury, SecondaryInjury)


#   plantid year PrimaryInjury SecondaryInjury OtherInjury is_injured
#1        1    1          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#2        1    2        Insect            <NA>        <NA>          1
#3        1    3          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#4        2    1          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#5        2    2          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#6        2    3          Rust            <NA>        <NA>          1
#7        3    1          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#8        3    2          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#9        3    3          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#10       4    1          Rust            <NA>        <NA>          1
#11       4    2          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
#12       4    3        Insect            <NA>        <NA>          1
#13       5    1    Snow break            <NA>        <NA>          1
#14       5    2          Rust            <NA>        <NA>          1
#15       5    3          <NA>            <NA>        <NA>          0
```